# Basic password authentication system app

Tags: c++, beginner, console, authentication

This is a console app I wrote for an end-of-chapter assignment in *Jumping into C++*. The parameters were for it to have a basic password system, and if you are eager, a multiple password / username system.  I am going through this book completely on my own free will.  It's not through a school assignment or whatnot.

It works quite well, but as I have a limited programming background, I wanted to post it here so any bad techniques or poor syntax could be brought to my attention.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string usrnam[] = { "admin", "user", "" };
string pasword[] = { "root", "default", ""};

string temp_pass;
string temp_usr;

bool loggedin;

int n = sizeof(usrnam) / sizeof(string);

int findPassword( string str[], int array_size, string query )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < array_size; i++ )
    {
        if ( str[i] == query )
    {
        return i;
    }
}
}

int commandC()
{
    int stage;
    cout << "Enter '1' for calculator: ";
    cin >> stage;
    switch(stage)
{
    case 1: {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Not fully developed" << endl << endl;

    }
}

cout << "_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-";
}

void login(string user, string pass){
     if ( pass == pasword[findPassword(usrnam, n, user)] )
     {
        cout << "Logged in as " << user << endl << endl;
        loggedin = true;
        commandC();
     }
}

void registerUser()
{
    string answer;
    cout << "No matches found in the database...would you like to make new account? (Y/N)";
    cin >> answer;
    if (answer == "y" || answer == "Y")
    {
        cout << "Please enter a username: ";
        cin >> usrnam[n-1];
        cout << "Please enter a password: ";
        cin >> pasword[n-1];

        login(usrnam[n-1],pasword[n-1]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter username: ";
    cin >> temp_usr;
    cout << "Enter password; ";
    cin >> temp_pass;

    login(temp_usr,temp_pass);

    if(!loggedin)
        registerUser();
}
```

Comment: is this `int n = sizeof(usrnam) / sizeof(string);` division, or are you initializing two variables on the same line?

Comment: That is some code I found while looking around on the web to fix a problem I was having. It determines how many entries there are in the array "usrnam"

Comment: Learn from [Ken Thompson's regret](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Kenneth_Thompson#Attributed): "If I had to redesign UNIX, I'd spell creat with an e."

Comment: @Malachi: It's a standard C idiom equivalent to int n = count(usrnam);

Comment: You should **never** actually store the password. If your password DB falls into bad hands the bad people can then use the same passwords for other systems your users uses. So always hash your passwords before storing. That way even if your password DB is stolen nobody will know the actual password.

Answer (score 14):

- Try using `std::vector` instead of arrays. As a result, you'll not be required to keep track of the `array_size` in a separate variable like `n` in your case.

  Something like this:

  ```
  std::vector<std::string> username;
  username.push_back("admin");
  //other entries go here
  std::vector<std::string> password;
  password.push_back("root");
  //other entries go here
  ```

  Then, the size of the `std::vector` is given by `size()`.
- Try to use proper names as variables. Avoid wrong spellings or short-names. Exact variable names make the code easy to understand, as the name represents the actual concept the variable is referring to.
- Also, in `registerUser()` the variable `answer` can just be a `char`. This will help in saving a little memory.
  Like:

  ```
  char answer;
  std::cin>>answer;
  if(answer=='y' || answer=='Y')
  {
      //code goes here
  }
  ```
- In your code, the method `commandC()` is defined to return an `int`. But it doesn't do so. Make the return type `void` instead.

  ```
  void CommandC()
  {
      //code goes here
  }
  ```
- Also, the `main()` method is defined to return an `int` too. It is a good practice to declare it like that, but make sure to return an integer. 0 (zero) is preferred as it refers to successful completion of main().

  ```
  int main()
  {
      //code goes here
      return 0; //indicates successful termination
  }
  ```

Comment: I was aware of the misspellings, but I am glad you brought it up. Thanks for the suggestions as well.

Comment: @Phaenomena I think you asked about `std` as I got a notification for the same. Nevertheless, `std` is a namespace which is like a scope resolver. Read more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

Comment: I did, but I had a second thought that I could just Google it and not bother you xD Thanks anyhow

Comment: @Phaenomena +1 :) Good to see your attitude to learn :)

Comment: This isn't Fortran. There's no reason to manage parallel arrays or vectors. Create a struct and then create a vector of that struct.

Comment: @jliv902 +1 Oh! I missed it. Thanks for reviewing the review.

Comment: If your program can not go wrong (ie there is no distinction between good and bad). Then it is best **not** to return anything from `main()`. As main is special the compiler will automatically add the `return 0;` for you and your non usage is an indication that the program has no failure state.

Comment: @jiliv902: Or have a `map` that stores the passwords, indexed by user name.

Answer (score 12):

You have some compiler warnings:

> ```
> $ clang++ -o console{,.cpp}
> console.cpp:24:1: warning: control may reach end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
> }
> ^
> console.cpp:41:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
> }
> ^
> 2 warnings generated.
> ```

You have a segfault:

> ```
> Enter username: a
> Enter password; b
> Segmentation fault: 11
> ```

For entering a wrong password, I wouldn't expect to be invited to create an account:

> ```
> Enter username: user
> Enter password; WrongPassword
> No matches found in the database...would you like to make new account? (Y/N)y
> Please enter a username: admin
> Please enter a password: LaxSecurity
> ```

If a password contains a space, weird things happen:

> ```
> Enter username: user
> Enter password; correct y horse battery staple
> No matches found in the database...would you like to make new account? (Y/N)Please enter a username: Please enter a password: Logged in as horse
>
> Enter '1' for calculator: _-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-
> ```

Comment: As for the first few problems, they may be fixed now as I've revised my code. The second "problem" isn't a problem at all, it's meant to be that way. And for the third problem, I'm currently working on a function that removes spaces from the input.

Comment: Stripping spaces is the wrong approach. Use `std::getline(std::cin, password)`.

Comment: So do I need to change all my other "cin >>" statements now? I've read that mixing getline and cin is not the best thing to do.

Comment: Well, you are expecting lines of input, not words, so they should all use `getline()`.

Comment: I replaced the username and password inputs to getline, but I left the others with cin. Good enough I guess. It still seems to accept the whitespaces though.

Comment: @Phaenomena: You would just need `getline()` with your string inputs.  `char`s and `int`s can still use `cin`.

Answer (score 9):

- These are all being used as global variables:

  > ```
  > string usrnam[] = { "admin", "user", "" };
  > string pasword[] = { "root", "default", ""};
  >
  > string temp_pass;
  > string temp_usr;
  >
  > bool loggedin;
  >
  > int n = sizeof(usrnam) / sizeof(string);
  > ```

  This is bad practice because any of these variables can be modified anywhere at any time, which is a source of bugs and maintenance issues.  Both of those initialized strings and `n` should be `const`, which will prevent them from being modified further.

  The rest of the variables should be declared in functions and possibly passed to other functions for use.  This will allow you to keep track of how they're being used.
- Passing in a C-style array isn't preferred:

  > ```
  > int findPassword( string str[], int array_size, string query ) {}
  > ```

  This will actually deprecate to a *pointer*, which is not what the user expects to happen.  This is also common practice in C, but you're writing in C++.

  As @gargankit mentioned, prefer to use an STL container such as `std::vector` in place of all the C-style arrays to avoid this deprecation.  It'll also no longer be necessary to pass in `array_size` since all STL containers know their sizes (accessible with the function `size()`).
- `switch` seems needless here:

  > ```
  > switch(stage)
  > {
  >     case 1: {
  >         cout << endl;
  >         cout << "Not fully developed" << endl << endl;
  >     }
  > }
  > ```

  If you only have one `case`, just use an `if`:

  ```
  if (stage == 1)
  {
      cout << endl;
      cout << "Not fully developed" << endl << endl;
  }
  ```

  You could also make the body just one line, and with `"\n"` instead of `std::endl`.  [The latter also flushes the buffer, which takes longer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).  No need to use it for every newline.

  ```
  cout << "\nNot fully developed\n\n";
  ```

Comment: I didn't notice that I copied you.  Imitation is the best flattery, no? :-D

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: No worries. :-) You didn't copy it *entirely*, plus you expanded on one of the variables quite effectively (minus the C-ness, haha).  I merely pointed its wrongfulness and why it's wrong.

Comment: Thank you kindly.  It is true what you say... every morning I wake up and say to myself, "Why did you waste your life with C!" ;-)

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: C still has its uses, and C++ is just another language.  Fortunately for you, you could easily focus on algorithms rather than having to utilize the STL (although I personally like the STL and I don't do too well with my own algorithms at times).

Answer (score 8):

In the following:

```
int findPassword( string str[], int array_size, string query )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < array_size; i++ )
    {
        if ( str[i] == query )
    {
        return i;
    }
}
}
```

If you use std::vector as suggested by gargankit, or you use std::array, you would be able to take advantage of the range-based for loops in C++.
Instead of:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i)
{
    if(str[i] == query)
    {
       return i;
    }
}
```

you would write

```
for(const auto & arrayElement : str)
{
    if(arrayElement == query)
    {
        // note in this case arrayElement is a string, not
        // an integer index into the array, so this would
        // require changing the return type of findPassword
        return arrayElement;
    }
}
```

The benefit of a range-based for loop is that you don't have to be concerned about the potential risk of stepping out of the bounds of the given container, in this case str.

If you are feeling adventurous you might also look into using the standard algorithms included in the STL and calling either std::find_if, or std::any_of to find the array element you are looking for.

For functions that you are writing which take parameters that you will not modify in the body of the function, prefer taking the parameters as const parameters to specify and enforce your intent not to modify those values.

For example in:

```
void login(string user, string pass){
     if ( pass == pasword[findPassword(usrnam, n, user)] )
     {
        cout << "Logged in as " << user << endl << endl;
        loggedin = true;
        commandC();
     }
}
```

You never modify the value of pass, and it would be particularly strange in this case if you did modify the password that the user was typing in. In such a case it is more clear and more correct to require pass be const in login:

```
void login(string user, const string pass){
     if ( pass == pasword[findPassword(usrnam, n, user)] )
     {
        cout << "Logged in as " << user << endl << endl;
        loggedin = true;
        commandC();
     }
}
```

You can probably also do this to user, but that would require also making user const in the findPassword function.

Also, for any variables that you pass along as const, consider passing them as "const &" so that you do not make any unnecessary copies of that data.

Comment: `pass` should actually be passed in as `const&`.  If you're not modifying an object, doing this would avoid unnecessary copying.

Comment: I attempted to change the findPassword loop, but it appears I am in "C++98 mode". I'm using Codeblocks. Should it be C++98 or should I change it?

Comment: If you can change it to C++11 you will be better off. C++11 is more modern and will help you develop better practices and habits that are up to date with the latest standard for C++. Also, the vast majority of C++11 still allows C++98 functionality so I doubt you'll run into too much trouble performing the exercises in your book even if the book is expecting C++98 as the compiler.

Comment: @Phaenomena: Range-based for-loops are only available in C++11.  In C++98, you can still use iterators by doing `for (auto iter = container.begin(); iter != container.end(); ++iter) {}`

Comment: @Jamal auto however is in C++11 not C++98.
So the loop may look more like 
    for(std::vector<int>::iterator iter = container.begin(); iter !- container.end(); ++iter) {}

Comment: @YoungJohn: Oh yeah, you're right. :-) I'm still used to using `auto`, apparently.

Answer (score 7):

You're using a lot of `global` variables, such as `bool loggedin;`.  It's best to keep a variable's scope as small as possible.  To make the scope smaller for `loggedin`, for example, remove this global declaration:

```
bool loggedin;
```

Do the following to the `login` function:

```
bool login(string user, string pass)
{
    bool loggedin; // Make a local copy of this in login

    if(pass == pasword[findPassword(usrnam, n, user)])
    {
        cout << "Logged in as " << user << endl << endl;
        loggedin = true;
        commandC();
    }
    else
    {
        loggedin = false; // Always make sure variables are initialized to something
    }

    return loggedin; // Return this value to calling function
}
```

Now you can call `login` like this:

```
int main()
{  
    cout << "Enter username: ";
    cin >> temp_usr;
    cout << "Enter password; ";
    cin >> temp_pass;

    bool loggedin = login(temp_usr,temp_pass); // Make another local copy of loggedin in main

    if(!loggedin)
        registerUser();
}
```

Comment: Regarding scope, you could just do `bool loggedin = login(temp_usr,temp_pass);` and remove the earlier declaration. :-)

Comment: @Jamal I'm paid by the line. ;-) Also, I have a heavy `C` background… so I'll blame that!

Comment: Forgive me.  Us humans are yet to truly understand the way of the code monkey. :-) And I have a C++ background (barely any C), so there's that.

Comment: @Jamal It's the convention, in C, to put all a function's variables at the top.  I bet you'd cringe looking at the stuff I've written! :-))

Comment: Eh, I'd just be bothered if there were a "list" of variables at the top of a function.

Comment: @Jamal Imagine declaring a variable at the top of a long function… and then not using it until the end. Insanity!

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey: If you're writing a long function in C, you're Doing It Wrong(TM).

Comment: @Matt I'm talking about long by C standards, which I'm sure is quite short by other language's standards.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of best practice, you should keep in mind that passwords should never be stored raw, only as salted hashes. If you are going to ever write a program that will handle passwords in actual use (not just as a programming exercise), you really need to read [Salted Password Hashing - Doing it Right](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm). (Even if not, it's still a good read anyway.)

The reason for this is not because your application necessarily needs to be secure, but to ensure someone doesn't hack your application and steal your users accounts for *other* services, because most people use the same username and password everywhere.

Also, one other feature that would normally be needed is the ability to store the user data in a file and read it when it starts, so it can persist between sessions, although this too is probably beyond the scope of the excersise.

With respect to other aspects of your code, it seems you are on the right track; everything else I can see has already been said by other users.

Comment: +1 - In addition to the possibility of leaching username/passwords for other sites, this also falls into practice like your not practicing. Raw passwords (or passwords storage done wrong) should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

you should look at the way you are indenting your code,  this piece of code almost confused me for a minute ( or two )

```
int findPassword( string str[], int array_size, string query )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < array_size; i++ )
    {
        if ( str[i] == query )
    {
        return i;
    }
}
}
```

it should look like this

```
int findPassword( string str[], int array_size, string query )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < array_size; i++ )
    {
        if ( str[i] == query )
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

it is always good to keep your indentations straight (even thought you could write the code without them)  it makes the code easier to read.

Comment: It's indented flawlessly in my IDE, but something got messed up while formatting it into my post. xD Thanks for bringing it up though.

Comment: what about that integer declaration?

Comment: Nevermind, I replied to your question

Answer (score 2):

Usually comment about this line (look it up in every other C++ review).

```
using namespace std;
```

Don't use C arrays. The C++ containers are much more useful. Every other answer has suggested you use `std::vector<std::string>` as a replacement. That again is a terrible idea. Your main usage pattern is searching. Use a data structure that is designed to be searched. `std::map<std::string, std::string>`

```
string usrnam[] = { "admin", "", "" };
string pasword[] = { "root", "default", ""};

// I would have used:

std::map<std::string, std::string> password = {{"admin","root"},{"user","default"}};
```

I can see putting the actual username/password in global scope (as it needs to be used from everywhere (not a great design but acceptable). But no other variables should be in the global scope they should be close to the point of usage.

```
string temp_pass;
string temp_usr;
```

This should have been const.
Your current design did not allow for modification of the username/password so this should have been const. But if you use a standard C++ container this becomes superfluous.

```
int n = sizeof(usrnam) / sizeof(string);

// Also note it is more traditional to write this as:
int n = sizeof(usrnam) / sizeof(usrnam[0]);

// This is because if you change the type of `usernam` this code is still
// correct. In your version you would need to change the code in two places.
```

C++ requires you to return a value at the end of a function:

```
int findPassword( string str[], int array_size, string query )
// This function does not return anything when the name is not
// found. This will result in hard to find errors.
```

When dealing with user input read a line at a time then parse the line.

```
cin >> stage;

// What happens if the user entered 1 12 <enter>
// The next time you are looking for input then you will read 12
// even though it is left over from this input.
// 
// Users interact with the terminal in lines.
// Because there input is not flushed until they hit `enter`
// they will hit enter after their input. The program does not recognize
// this and the operator>> does not remove the resulting '\n' character
// from the input. So if the next interaction with the user is getline()
// you will mysteriously read an empty line even if the user enters text.
```

Always use a `break` at the end of `case`. The exception is so rare that it should be well documented with comments.

Always put a `default` in a switch. Even if the default (throws an exception). An exception is better than the code blowing up because some other piece of code has changed.

```
switch(stage)
{
    case 1: {
       cout << endl;
        cout << "Not fully developed" << endl << endl;
    }
}
```

Password design.
Absolutely **NEVER** store the plain text version of the password. Always use a one way hash `like md5`  on the password and store the hash of the password.

Many people use the same password on multiple systems. If you lose control of your passwords then your have compromised your customers security.

So accept the password in plan text but always store it has a hash. You may also want to read up on slating the password first.

Comment: +1.  Now it seems obvious that `std::map` is best for searching.  My instinct still seems to be to almost always recommend `std::vector` in place of a C-style array (although my idea was a bit more general as I was mentioning why passing in a C-style array in C++ is not a good idea).